# How do I join two series into a single dataframe when one is indexed with numbers and the other with dates

Tags: pandas, dataframe, datetime, indexing, series

I'm having trouble combining my Y_test data beside my predicted_tuned data, i've tried every example I could come across yet when I set the index for datetime I seem to still get a big error as NAN for where the index's do not match up, as you can see in the attempt below, which is one of many, there are just as many dates as there are numbers in the df and df2 which I just converted into a `df = Y_test` I also tried  to set the index to datetime but I still do not get the numbers aligned beside the dates asIi'm looking for,

again to reiterate essentially I am trying to align the two series side by side and set the index as datetime, yet when I do that I get a bunch of NAN values, Thank you in advance for considering to help me on this problem!

```
   pd.concat([df, df2])
    179                                                                0.002
    180                                                                0.003
    181                                                                0.005
    182                                                                0.006
    183                                                                 0.01
                                                 ...                        
    2021-03-18 00:00:00                                                0.007
    2021-03-25 00:00:00                                                0.042
    2021-04-01 00:00:00                                                0.054
    2021-04-12 00:00:00                                                0.011
    date                   179    2.037e-03
    180    3.190e-03
    181    4.505...
    Length: 91, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rename columns by setting the `.columns` attribute. Then to stack side by side, specify `axis=1` for [**`concat()`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) and finally set the index to `date`:

```py
df.columns = ['date', 'predicted']
df2.columns = ['date', 'actual']
pd.concat([df, df2], axis=1).set_index('date')
```

Comment: The first row of the df is '179'     '2.037e-03' and the first row of df2 is '2020-04-30 00:00:00'                                                 '0.024'  so either way i try this im getting back "None of ['2020-04-30 00:00:00'] are in the columns"  I'm thinking to possibly export each as a csv and manually add the date column on top but do you know how i could do this without exporting and re importing? As in the series date is not one of the columns at this point i will keep working forward with this and keep u updated though

Comment: What i ended up doing to work around was export to csv then import and rename column colnames=['date', 'actual'] 
df = pd.read_csv('yo.csv', names=colnames, header=None)

Comment: Thank you for the help, now i just gotta figure out why they aren't on the same scale haha i appreciate it

Comment: @CodyVandervoort if you just need to rename the columns, you can set the .columns attribute without going through the export/import csv routine (updated the answer to show this)

Comment: Thanks for that, i've found myself doing this work around a few times haha

Answer (score 0):

The final work around I needed to do was to first rename the columns to 'date' by exporting as csv then reimporting with the following code

```
   df2.to_csv('yo.csv')

colnames=['date', 'actual'] 
user1 = pd.read_csv('yo.csv', names=colnames, header=None)

df.to_csv('yo1.csv')

colnames=['date', 'predicted'] 
user2 = pd.read_csv('yo1.csv', names=colnames, header=None)

pd.concat([user1, user2], axis=1).set_index('date')

                              actual             predicted
date        
(nan, nan)  MSFT_pred   0.000e+00
(2020-04-30 00:00:00, 179.0)    0.024201106326536603    2.037e-03
(2020-05-07 00:00:00, 180.0)    -0.01686254903583162    3.190e-03
(2020-05-14 00:00:00, 181.0)    0.018717373876389054    4.505e-03
(2020-05-21 00:00:00, 182.0)    -0.000981754619259867   5.655e-03
(2020-05-29 00:00:00, 183.0)    0.02132616076987759 1.038e-02
(2020-06-08 00:00:00, 184.0)    0.0030745362797475195   1.840e-02
(2020-06-15 00:00:00, 185.0)    0.059733833525184465    -8.471e-03
(2020-06-22 00:00:00, 186.0)    -0.010676658312346099   1.963e-03
(2020-06-29 00:00:00, 187.0)    0.04825255850145016 1.271e-02
(2020-07-07 00:00:00, 188.0)    0.00048009595166487173  -3.963e-03
(2020-07-15 00:00:00, 189.0)    0.017675967314019658    1.315e-02
(2020-07-22 00:00:00, 190.0)    -0.03699223319804901    7.459e-03
(2020-07-29 00:00:00, 191.0)    0.0425963854255107  6.393e-04
(2020-08-05 00:00:00, 192.0)    -0.017767412527132542   8.299e-03
(2020-08-12 00:00:00, 193.0)    0.004849289374926791    1.229e-02
(2020-08-19 00:00:00, 194.0)    0.053163269514577394    -7.205e-04
(2020-08-26 00:00:00, 195.0)    0.04638640608165456 -2.941e-03
(2020-09-02 00:00:00, 196.0)    -0.12041441937020192    1.215e-03
(2020-09-10 00:00:00, 197.0)    -0.012050617841010691   1.572e-02
(2020-09-18 00:00:00, 198.0)    0.03640692855683092 1.282e-02
(2020-09-25 00:00:00, 199.0)    -0.007874252996166398   1.493e-03
(2020-10-02 00:00:00, 200.0)    0.04560030760287681 6.036e-03
(2020-10-09 00:00:00, 201.0)    0.017682541657954687    6.680e-03
(2020-10-20 00:00:00, 202.0)    -0.006543498136577064   3.152e-03
(2020-10-27 00:00:00, 203.0)    -0.03250388362265788    -7.606e-03
(2020-11-03 00:00:00, 204.0)    0.021944140659009292    1.106e-02
(2020-11-10 00:00:00, 205.0)    0.016217814956357657    1.540e-02
(2020-11-19 00:00:00, 206.0)    0.013141777478138827    8.397e-03
(2020-11-30 00:00:00, 207.0)    0.0010271171517945987   9.058e-03
(2020-12-09 00:00:00, 208.0)    0.0347070301815533  1.084e-02
(2020-12-16 00:00:00, 209.0)    0.00790377030467937 3.130e-03
(2020-12-23 00:00:00, 210.0)    0.006314251899552481    6.853e-03
(2021-01-05 00:00:00, 211.0)    -0.013723872690842853   7.528e-03
(2021-01-13 00:00:00, 212.0)    0.039115811401939204    1.702e-03
(2021-01-22 00:00:00, 213.0)    0.02625125481157209 -1.252e-02
(2021-02-02 00:00:00, 214.0)    0.01763006225325281 3.198e-03
(2021-02-09 00:00:00, 215.0)    0.0040628812983873885   6.399e-03
(2021-02-17 00:00:00, 216.0)    -0.04031875139405816    4.501e-03
(2021-02-25 00:00:00, 217.0)    -0.009918495072427369   1.617e-02
(2021-03-04 00:00:00, 218.0)    0.044848671154583464    7.920e-03
(2021-03-11 00:00:00, 219.0)    -0.027403675161880692   1.280e-02
(2021-03-18 00:00:00, 220.0)    0.006996940936046414    1.904e-02
(2021-03-25 00:00:00, 221.0)    0.04218118715262609 9.114e-03
(2021-04-01 00:00:00, 222.0)    0.05420837163083725 4.867e-04
(2021-04-12 00:00:00, 223.0)    0.010997824269626477    2.224e-03
(date, nan) 179 2.037e-03\n180 3.190e-03\n181 4.5...    NaN
```